# How does C# call a method before it has been defined in the program?

Tags: c#, oop, methods, call, clr

I am very surprised that the following code block still executes despite the method not being defined or known yet to the compiler.  I first noticed this in another program and then created this test case.  Sure enough, it works.  In python or JavaScript, this would not be the case.  It would throw an undefined function error.  That's why I always make sure to define the function first, then call it.

I did some research and while I couldn't find anything explicitly referring to this phenomena, I suspect this is possibly the main difference between scripting languages (python, JS) and languages with a Common language runtime interface. Perhaps the compiler runs through everything and converts it to machine code and by then it is already aware of all fields, properties, and methods contained within by the time it starts instruction execution.

Am I on the right track?

```
using System;

namespace TestingGround
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Method call
            Console.WriteLine(GetSumOfFirstTwoOrDefault(null));  // output: 0
            Console.WriteLine(GetSumOfFirstTwoOrDefault(new int[0]));  // output: 0
            Console.WriteLine(GetSumOfFirstTwoOrDefault(new[] { 3, 5, 5 }));  // output: 8 
            
            //Define Method for returning the sum of the first two integers in a list
            int GetSumOfFirstTwoOrDefault(int[] numbers)
            {
                //normal input 1 x array of numbers
                //normal output 1 x scalar that is the sum of the first two numbers only
                //edge case - if input array null / empty
                //Most concise with non null conditional operator and null condiitonal operator
                //normal implementation if array null handle return 0, if array.length < 2 return 0, else 
                //add array[0] + array[1]

                
                if ((numbers?.Length ?? 0) < 2)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
            }
                             
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# is a compiled language. It is compiled first, and then that binary is executed. This is the way most languages worked until the likes of Python, Javascript, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on the language. Since you mentioned a few others, let's compare them on that count:

- C# doesn't care about the order in which members or types are declared. As long as a method is visible from the current location in code you can call it. In your case you used a local method. This is effectively the same as declaring the method in the class itself, except that you can only call it from one method. If you [run your code through the compiler and a decompiler after that](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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), you can see that the local function is instead declared on the class, just with a compiler-generated name.
- In JavaScript or Python you have to take care where you call the function. Sure, in the following snippet, things won't work:

  ```js
  foo()

  function foo() {
    console.log('Someone called me!')
  }
  ```

  This is because the first line is attempted to be executed before the rest has been read. However, with a more C#-like style of code this is not the case anymore:

  ```py
  def main():
    foo()

  def foo():
    print('Someone called me!')
      main()
  ```

  This now works, because the *content* of the functions is parsed, but not executed immediately. And by the time we end up *calling* `main`, the `foo` function is defined and callable. In a way, this mimics how C# works as well. The compiler assembles everything together and by the time the code is actually executed, things are in place and can be found.
- Now, in older languages like C or Pascal, there's a requirement for functions to be declared before you can call them. This is because back then computing power was scarce and single-pass compilers – compilers that went just once over the source code and spit out object or assembler code right away – were common. And in order to generate the code for a function call you need to know what arguments the function takes and what it returns – its signature. So in C you'd have something like this:

  ```c
  void foo(void); // forward declaration

  void main(void) {
    foo();
  }

  void foo(void) { // actual implementation
    printf("Someone called me!\n");
  }
  ```

  The reason here is a bit different, but kinda comparable. While an interpreter executing a line would surely have to know about a function it's supposed to call, the compiler (assuming it can't go back) has to as well.

Coming back to C#: The C# compiler isn't a single-pass compiler and takes multiple passes over the source code. At least once to gather all types and members and their respective visibility (just the declarations, though), and at least once more to generate the actual IL code. And when that happens, the information about what names are visible from where and what they are, is already available to be used.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't care about where you define a method. It uses hoisting so all method definitions are considered to be at the top of their scope. See here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting